# ALEXA VOICE SERVICE RESPONSE : "sorry I am not sure" or "hmmm i dont know that"

Tags: ios, voice-recognition, alexa-skills-kit, avs

i m integrating alexa voice service is my ios app ...... now i m hearing alexa voice response as sorry i don't know that ... what changes has to be done to resolve this issue .. what updates have taken place in alexa voice service .. if any one can guide me thru it will be of great help ...i m not getting end point directive "expectspeech" to process further in this scenario ... thanks in advance .....

Answer (score 1):

It's not really possible to understand the problem here, but I believe there are a few possible scenarios:

1. Maybe you have done something wrong with your code over the past 10 days. Go check it out.
2. If you didn't make any changes at all, check for any updates in the ASK specs or AWS Lambda specs (if you're using Lambda to host your Alexa Skill)

Comment: no since same is working good in android app as per sample code in amazon aws . there is no reference for ios objective c or swift for alexa voice service api integration with updates to latest version...